# Meteor.js - Failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-up

My app is using Meteor Up X or the mupx for deployment. Last week it was running just fine. But right now its not loading. It just displays a plain white background and takes a long time to load. After the long load, when I checked the console the error it displayed this:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

No problem in running it in local. I even tried running it local with the production database just to check if it was a database problem but no it still runs in local. I found this https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/516 which was close to my problem but disabling the adblocker didn't help. I also tried accessing it in other computer with no adblocker. No hope.

Comment: I'd post on the github issues of the repo

Comment: Now its working. weird